# S3 static hosting - 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to s3 static hosting working on only my IP, but when I remove all public access and then add a bucket policy that only allows my IP, I still get 403 forbidden? What am I missing?

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyId2",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIPmix",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "ARN: arn:aws:s3:::testbucket50000/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "*"
                },
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "72.123.30.117/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You still need to designate the bucket as public access. 
It will be a public, but only for your IP, per your bucket policy.

Comment: I disabled block public access so shouldn't it be able to reach my IP? I'm not sure what you mean otherwise

Comment: Correct. But you need to enable public access first. Then you can further limit access by IP. But the overall bucket must have public access.

Comment: Where do I enable public access? bucket acl? I added a new screenshot above and added public access through acl, but that's not it. Can you specifically tell me where to go?

Comment: See where it allows Public Access to Everyone? Can you set that?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need

```
"NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "*"
                },`
```

this piece is enough

```
  "Condition": {
    "IpAddress": {
      "aws:SourceIp": "72.123.30.117/32"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I switched out the piece per your recommendation, but that wasn't the problem. Still get 403 forbidden

Comment: are you sure your IP is correct by checking https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why do you have the `resource` as `Resource": "ARN: arn:aws:s3:::testbucket50000/*"`

It should just be:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket50000/*"
```

That makes it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyId2",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIPmix",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket50000/*",
            "Condition": {

                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "72.123.30.117/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```